# Suppressing a feature form when a feature is added in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I want to suppress the feature form when a feature is added to a layer using PyQGIS.
How to achieve this.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
formConfig = layer.editFormConfig()
formConfig.suppress()
layer.setEditFormConfig(formConfig)
```

This is the answer I got for QGIS 3.32v:

```
    formConfig = layer.editFormConfig()
formConfig.setSuppress(QgsEditFormConfig.FeatureFormSuppress)
layer.setEditFormConfig(formConfig)
```

But I am facing the error :

**TypeError: QgsEditFormConfig.setSuppress(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'EnumMeta'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with [setSupress method](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsEditFormConfig.html#qgis.core.QgsEditFormConfig.setSuppress) in QGIS version 3.28

```
formConfig = layer.editFormConfig()
formConfig.setSuppress(1)
layer.setEditFormConfig(formConfig)
```

and this in [QGIS version 3.32 or higher](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/Qgis.html#qgis.gui.Qgis.AttributeFormSuppression):

```
formConfig = layer.editFormConfig()
formConfig.setSuppress(QgsEditFormConfig.SuppressOff)
layer.setEditFormConfig(formConfig)
```

Comment: I am getting this error - TypeError: QgsEditFormConfig.setSuppress(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'EnumMeta' when I run the 3.32 version's code.

Comment: i Edited my answer. check this

Comment: Thank you, this works